# Load balance with thrift and nginx

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, thrift, service-discovery

I have the following thrift server (socket), listening for connections on a specific host/port.

```
 final TProtocolFactory factory = new TBinaryProtocol.Factory();
        TNonblockingServerTransport serverTransport = new TNonblockingServerSocket(serverPort);

 final SignatureService.Processor theProcessor = new SignatureService.Processor(new SignatureServiceFacade());
 TServer server = new THsHaServer(new THsHaServer.Args(serverTransport).processor(theProcessor).
                protocolFactory(factory).
                minWorkerThreads(minThreads).
                maxWorkerThreads(maxThreads));
```

And following client connection:

```
clientTransport = new TFramedTransport(new TSocket(signatureHost, signaturePort));
final TProtocol theProtocol = new TBinaryProtocol(clientTransport);
client = new SignatureService.Client(theProtocol);
clientTransport.open();
//call the business specific method
client.doStuff(param1, param2, param3);
```

As we can see in the code above I need to provide the host and port in order to open a connection with the server.

But I want to use a service discovery with load balance support, because I'll have multiple instances of my service running.

Anybody has an example of this using nginx? All the examples is using regular http rest based applications.

Tks in advance.